# Popen reading from stdout takes a very very long time

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to capture the output from a shell command (npm --version) however only the first line is read and the process does not end.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['npm', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
proc.wait()
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line.decode("utf-8").strip())
print("does not get here?!")
```

Any idea how I could detect the end of this process?.

If I open a cmd and execute 'npm --version', it ends as expected so I do not know why this done in the above does not end.

Some extra information that maybe of use!...

- npm is installed via nvm
- this is used to manage node installs via symlinks
- npm from what I can see is a .cmd file that executes node?

Running this in python command prompt...

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['npm', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
>>> proc.wait()
0
>>> proc.stdout.readline()
'6.10.3\n'
>>> proc.stdout.readline()
''
```

Now the second .readline() takes a very very long time to complete!

Comment: try to add shell=True for Popen(). As far as I remember npm is bat-file in windows.

Comment: It already has that (scroll to the right), Not putting it results in file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE in popen.wait() will cause a deadlock. Try using communicate() to avoid that.
This is due to other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.
See this documentation on how to use communicate ()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the console output when you manually type on the command prompt please.

The code you have shared works on my machine and i am assuming it may have to do something with the way npm is installed. In any case can you share the output from command console.

Thanks
Pushpa

Comment: can you also use :      Add close_fds=True to the call to subprocess.Popen()

Comment: close_fds has no effect on this issue.

Comment: npm is installed via nvm, i also suspect this maybe the route cause of my issue

Comment: regular installed npm (via node installer) works as expected